# How do I access process.env.* from @nestjs/config in my Strategy service constructor?

Tags: typescript, nestjs, nestjs-config, nestjs-passport

I tried setting isGlobal: true in app.modele.ts but process.env.* returned undefined.

```js
@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      isGlobal: true,
      envFilePath,
    }),
    
    ...
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Next, I tried injecting ConfigService in my Strategy class but still getting undefined.

```js
import { Strategy } from 'passport-auth0';
import { PassportStrategy } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { Injectable, Logger } from "@nestjs/common";
import { Request } from "express";
import { ConfigService } from "@nestjs/config";

@Injectable()
export class Auth0Strategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {

  private readonly logger = new Logger(Auth0Strategy.name);

  constructor(private configService: ConfigService) {
    super({
      domain: configService.get<string>('AUTH0_DOMAIN'),
      clientID: configService.get<string>('AUTH0_CLIENT_ID'),
      clientSecret: configService.get<string>('AUTH0_CLIENT_SECRET'),
      callbackURL: configService.get<string>('AUTH0_CALLBACK_URL'),
      passReqToCallback: true
    });
  }

  async validate(req: Request, accessToken: string, refreshToken: string, extraParams, profile, done) {

    ...
  }
}
```

I am new to NodeJS, NestJS, Typescript,... coming from a Java Spring background. Any help appreciated!

Comment: Did you add a `.env` file in the root of the project? Or have you passed environment variables?

Comment: What you have should be fine and valid\

Comment: Yes, I have an .env.dev file and it is loaded in the AppModule, see my post above. The loading of the ConfigModule seems to occur after services are injected based on debugging the code.

If I pass the information as environment variables, I get the correct info from process.env.*.

Answer (score 0):

add ConfigurationModule in your project

```
@Module({
    imports:[ConfigModule.forRoot({
        envFilePath: ['your env name'],
        load:[configuration],
        isGlobal: true
    })],
})
export class ConfigurationModule {}
```

note: configuration is for db configuration

and then import ConfigurationModule in your appmodule

note: use process.env like this:

```
domain: process.env.AUTH0_DOMAIN
```

you dont need to define configService in constructor